# RestClient.get really slow to download small file

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I'm trying to download a small zip file and Ruby RestClient library is super slow. Downloading via browser takes <1sec. But it takes minutes with Ruby.

Why might that be?

Example:

```
require 'rest-client'

RestClient.get("http://prd-enforce-xfr-02.dol.gov/data_catalog/OSHA/osha_accident_abstract_20161013.csv.zip")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that server has a broken IPv6 AAAA record.

```
prd-enforce-xfr-02.dol.gov has address 63.106.133.229
prd-enforce-xfr-02.dol.gov has IPv6 address 2607:f250:d008:2029:63:106:133:129
```

I'm not able to connect to the server at all over IPv6. Downloading with wget, it falls back to IPv4 after the timeout.

```
$ wget --timeout=20 http://prd-enforce-xfr-02.dol.gov/data_catalog/OSHA/osha_accident_abstract_20161019.csv.zip
--2016-10-19 22:40:24--  http://prd-enforce-xfr-02.dol.gov/data_catalog/OSHA/osha_accident_abstract_20161019.csv.zip
Resolving prd-enforce-xfr-02.dol.gov (prd-enforce-xfr-02.dol.gov)... 2607:f250:d008:2029:63:106:133:129, 63.106.133.229
Connecting to prd-enforce-xfr-02.dol.gov (prd-enforce-xfr-02.dol.gov)|2607:f250:d008:2029:63:106:133:129|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to prd-enforce-xfr-02.dol.gov (prd-enforce-xfr-02.dol.gov)|63.106.133.229|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

Under the hood in rest-client, Ruby Net::HTTP is probably doing a similar sort of timeout. I imagine browsers are much smarter about doing a fast fallback. Unfortunately I'm not sure there's a way in rest-client to disable IPv6.

With raw Net::HTTP you can set the `local_host` to a local IPv4 address to force IPv4 use.